# Автозапуск программы при старте сервера

Tags: linux, сервер, faq, автозапуск

Как автоматически запускать программу при старте сервера? Без входа пользователя.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для начала, следует выяснить, какая из систем инициализации используется в вашем дистрибутиве. Это могут быть SysVInit, Systemd, Upstart, daemontools/runit/s6 или что-то более экзотическое.

Если дистрибутив современный и популярный - в нём, скорее всего, будет использоваться Systemd. Если дистрибутив древний - то там будет SysVInit. Ну а между этими крайностями может происходить всё что угодно.

Далее, следует искать способ сделать искомое уже в рамках вашей системы инициализации.

Ниже я привожу примерные способы добиться желаемого в разных системах инициализации - но лучше смотрите документацию.

---

### Systemd, признак наличия - директория /etc/systemd и программа systemctl

Для автозапуска программы на системе с systemd нужно создать unit-файл и положить его в директорию /etc/systemd/system/

Имя файла будет идентификатором службы. Расширение у файла должно быть `.service`

Минимальный файл:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/program
WorkingDirectory=...
User=...
Group=...

[Unit]
After=network.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Здесь строка `After=network.target` означает, что службу нужно загружать только после того как сетевые подключения начнут работать. А `WantedBy=multi-user.target` означает, что служба должна загружаться при обычном старте сервера.

Также тут предполагается, что программа после запуска просто начнёт работать, и будет работать пока пока не получит сигнал SIGTERM. Если программа должна поработать и перестать - надо ещё дописать в раздел `[Service]` настройку `Type=oneshot`. Ну а если программа - классический демон, то её надо прописывать `Type=forking` и настройки `ExecStop`, `PIDFile`

За дополнительными настройками можно заглянуть в `man systemd.unit`, `man systemd.service` и `man systemd.exec`

Теперь осталось включить службу: `systemctl enable имя_службы` и запустить её: `systemctl start имя_службы`.

---

### SysVInit, признак наличия - директории /etc/rc.d и /etc/init.d (последняя также может находиться по пути /etc/rc.d/init.d) и обязательное отсутствие признаков других систем инициализации

Другие системы инициализации могут частично поддерживать sysvinit-скрипты, но нет смысла составлять новый sysvinit-скрипт если можно составить что-то другое.

Тут проще всего добавить запуск вашей программы в файл rc.local:

```
#!/bin/bash

/path/to/program &
exit 0
```

Но если её при этом нужно ещё и останавливать - придётся писать полноценный скрипт в директории /etc/init.d:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    start)
        команды для запуска демона
    ;;
    stop)
        команды для остановки демона
    ;;
esac
```

Также могут понадобиться команды status, restart, reload и пр. Посмотрите как написаны остальные скрипты в папке /etc/init.d

Если запускаемая программа не является демоном - придётся также найти и использовать обертку-демонизатор, вроде программы start-stop-daemon

Не забудьте сделать скрипт исполняемым (`chmod +x /etc/init.d/имя`)

После создания нового скрипта в папке init.d нужно его включить, сделав жесткие ссылки в папке /etc/rc.d. Обычно они делаются вот так:

```
update-rc.d имя defaults
update-rc.d имя enable
```

Также возможен вариант с chkconfig, но тут придётся добавить в скрипт комментарий специального вида:

```
# chkconfig: - 98 02

chkconfig --add имя
```

Возможен и вариант что у вас настолько старый дистрибутив, что нужные ссылки придётся делать вручную. Это уже выходит за рамки ответа, гуглите структуру rc.d и уровни запуска

---

### Upstart, признаки - директория /etc/init

Тут нужно составить конфиг и положить его в /etc/init

```
exec /path/to/program
start on runlevel [23]
```

---

### runit, признаки - директории /etc/sv, /etc/runit и /etc/service (или /var/service)

Нужно создать каталог /etc/sv/имя_службы, а в нём - файл исполняемый run:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /path/to/program
```

Теперь этот сервис можно включить командой

```
ln -s /etc/sv/имя_службы /etc/service/имя_службы
```

Comment: *Ответ я писал не проверяя, просто собирал фрагменты манов, так что возможны ошибки. Прошу поправить меня если вы их заметите.*

Comment: Спасибо за подробный, пошаговый ответ! +1

Comment: Конечно от вида программ есть некоторые ньюансы)