# Деплой сервера nodeJS на Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, развертывание

У меня есть 2 сервера: веб-сокетный и http. Они оба относятся к одному проекту. Как можно сделать автоматический запуск этих двух серверов на Ubuntu 18.04 (чтобы, к примеру, после внеплановой перезагрузки физического сервера они автоматически запускались) без использования PM2 и прочих модулей?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968702

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно создать в системе сервис для обслуживания твоего приложения. Тут есть быстрый гайд https://tibbo.com/ru/linux/nodejs/service-file.html