# Перезапуск приложения при вылете

Tags: ubuntu, сервер

Нашел готовый сервер для программы, но он вылетает. Как можно при вылете приложения на убунту его автоматически запустить? Объясните школьнику пошагово.

Comment: Пока в голову пришла идея, мониторить текщие процессы, и при отсутствии нужного запускать его заново.
Собственно для этих задач, можно накидать простенький bash-скрипт и например, через cron запускать его с необходимой частотой

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автозапуск программы при старте сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968702/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему зацикленным баш скриптом

Answer (score 1):

Написать unit файл для systemd -- самый правильный вариант. `man systemd.service` и `man systemd.unit` Как выглядят готовые юниты -- смотреть в `/usr/lib/systemd/system`.