# Автозапуск скрипта в линукс

Tags: linux, сервер, raspberry-pi, автозапуск

Сап Стэк.
Такая проблема.
Купил одноплатник для школьного проекта.
Типа домашний сервер для бытовых нужд.
Скрипт, который нужно запускать работает исправно. Он всего один.
А вот как поместить его в автозапуск я не знаю.
Помоги, а?

Comment: Обратитесь к документации той операционной системы, которая установлена на этом одноплатнике

Comment: @ andreymal Да тут не к документации одноплатника нужно обращаться, а к системе. Обычная убунто-образная система, но без графики.

Comment: Я ж и говорю — к документации операционной системы. А понятие «убунто-образное» всё равно слишком широкое, чтобы можно было дать какой-то конкретный ответ

Comment: Что значит автозапуск ? Запуск по времени или запуск при старте системы ? 
100 процентов у вас systemd, стартуйте через него - вот пример `https://better-coding.com/autostart-how-to-run-a-service-on-linux-boot-time-using-systemd/`

если нужно по времени, стартуйте кроном.

Comment: засуньте в cron задание `@reboot root /path/script.sh`

Comment: Дабы не ломать себе мозг куда ж его правильно засунут, посмотри если у тебя есть файл ls -l /etc/rc.local, то можешь запуск скрипта дописать туда, этот файл обычно выполняется в конце инициализации всех служб/демонов. и обычно присутствует во всех дебиан-подобных дистрибутивах в целях совместимости.

Comment: Какой дистрибутив?

Comment: Armbian Установил на плату Orange pi zero

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автозапуск программы при старте сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968702/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

1. Во многих дистрибутивах есть файл /etc/rc.local. Если он есть, то можно вписать скрипт туда. Только не забудь символ & после команды.
2. Если есть cron, то можно запустить с помощью него, добавив в файл /etc/crontab

   @reboot <пользователь> <скрипт>
3. Если используется systemd, то можно создать unit, который будет выполняться при старте системы