# Задержка при запуске терминала в Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, консоль

На версии 18.04 ничего подобного не было. Терминал запускался мгновенно. Сейчас, после того, как открылось окно терминала, наступает длительная пауза. Около минуты не происходит вообще ничего. Можно попытаться что-то набирать, интерпретатор ещё не запущен.

Спустя продолжительное время в окне терминала появляется сообщение:

```
In order to daemonize you must specify a log file, you can use /dev/stdout to log to screen even as a daemon
```

Смысл сообщения для меня абсолютно загадочен. Кого нужно запустить как демон? И зачем?

После появления этого сообщения выскакивает стандартный промпт Shell и дальше всё работает нормально.  О чём говорит это сообщение?

Comment: очевидно, что в стартовых скриптах запускается что-то, надолго задерживающее процесс. для начала разбирательства стоит запустить `$ bash` и `$ bash -l` и оценить время запуска.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin попробовал оба варианта. Загадочное сообщение выдаётся в обоих вариантах. Задержка ощущается тоже в обоих вариантах, но меньше, чем если запускать терминал из меню.

Comment: ну, вот и настало время отладки. `$ bash -x` и смотрите, что у вас вызывается.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Напишите ответ - я Вам "+" поставлю: "calibre-server --daemonize". Проблема стала понятна. Непонятно только как калибре сделать запускаемой при старте компа.  Давным-давно был файл /etc/local в который можно было всякую хрень писать. А как сегодня - не знаю.

Comment: `/etc/rc.local`. нынче не используется. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/968702/178576 // https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/471824/110559

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin -"нынче не используется" Да, сделал запуск как сервис systemd и всё стало ОК.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

очевидно, что в стартовых скриптах запускается что-то, надолго задерживающее процесс инициализации оболочки.

запустите используемую в качестве оболочки программу с опцией `-x` (включение [трассировки](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#set)):

```
$ $SHELL -x
```

и увидите, запуск каких именно программ тормазит работу.