# Как добавить в автозапуск Ubuntu - .NET приложение

Tags: ubuntu, .net-core, .net-5

Скомпилировал консольное приложение .NET 5.0 для Ubuntu так: `dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.16.04-x64 --self-contained`
Перенес папку publish на VDS сервер
Потом дал разрешения `chmod 777 ./Server`
После чего я могу запустить приложение `./Server`

Но как мне мне добавить его автозапуск? Чтобы он запускался после перезагрузки сервера. Т.е. чтобы при создании какой-либо сессии высвечивалась консоль приложения, а не сервера.
Не очень силен в Linux, везде пишут разные варианты автозапуска, ничего похожего не могу найти.

Чтобы вместо всего этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Было сразу окно консольного приложенния:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Инструкция как создать сервис `systemd`](https://medium.com/@benmorel/creating-a-linux-service-with-systemd-611b5c8b91d6)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автозапуск программы при старте сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968702/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: `Т.е. чтобы при создании какой-либо сессии высвечивалась консоль приложения, а не сервера.` — а вот тут не понятно. если трактовать написанное буквально, то это совершенно другой вопрос, никак не связанный со всем остальным изложенным.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Скрипт для systemctl пробовал создавать, то ли я что-то не так сделал, то ли это вообще не будет работать как я хотел. Дополнил вопрос картинками.

Comment: а почему не в фоне?

Comment: @eri А если он будет работать в фоне, в процессе его можно будет запустить и проверить? Допустим это приложение после запуска просто начинает считать от 0 до бесконечности, если я его после какого-то времени запущу и захочу посмотреть сколько он насчитал - он мне покажет 0 и начнет заново, или покажет цифру сколько насчитал?

Comment: так лог на что? если лог не подходит - можно запустить в screen.
просто терминалов может быть много, обычно не нужно запускать это всё в каждом

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657290/191416