# Создать из Flask - приложения демон на Linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, flask, демон

У меня есть приложение на python Flask.
Запускаю его через консоль

```
python3 app.py
```

Но хотелось бы сделать из приложения демона, который бы стартовал при запуске системы (Linux CentOS).
Как это сделать? Может есть хороший пример или подробная инструкция?
Спасибо.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/southbridge/blog/255845/

Comment: Благодарю, ознакомлюсь

Comment: [Автозапуск программы при старте сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968702)

Comment: На ArchWiki есть набор информативных статей про systemd https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Супер! Большое спасибо

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657290/191416