Проверить работу cron модуля
Установил OC Ubunto
Необходимо добавить задачу в крон.
Перехожу в директорию: /var/spool/cron/crontabs, пустая, создаю файл с именем root в нем прописываю задачу.
При перезапуске сервера, должны по идеи исполняться все задачи в созданном файле. Но этого не происходит.
Либо крон не запускается и не исполняет при старте, либо команда с ошибкой.
Вопрос, вопрос собственно по модулю sudo Manticore
Установил, настроил, запустил, все работает. Проблема в том, что при перезагрузке сервера, необходимо по новой запускать модуль. А в кроне я выставил обновление таблиц для мантикоре и не совсем понимаю как добавить задачу на автозапуск модуля.
Вероятно это делается по другому. Подскажите пожалуйста, что необходимо сделать, чтобы при рестарте сервера. Manticore автоматически запускался...?
Дополнение
/usr/lib/systemd/system/manticore.service

Содержимое файла
[Unit]
Description=Manticore Search Engine
After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Documentation=https://manual.manticoresearch.com/, man:searchd(1)

[Service]
Type=forking
User=manticore
Group=manticore
RuntimeDirectory=manticore
# Run ExecStart with User=manticore / Group=manticore
ExecStart=/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/manticoresearch/manticore.conf $_ADDITIONAL_SEARCHD_PARAMS
ExecStop=/usr/bin/searchd --config /etc/manticoresearch/manticore.conf --stopwait
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGTERM
SendSIGKILL=no
LimitNOFILE=65536
LimitCORE=infinity
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
Restart=on-failure
TimeoutStartSec=infinity
PIDFile=/var/run/manticore/searchd.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=manticore.service
Alias=searchd.service

Далее в каталоге
/etc/systemd/system/

Создал символическу ссылку с именем
 /etc/systemd/system/manticore.service

Путь указал
/usr/lib/systemd/system/manticore.service

По результату, при перезапуске сервера, вынужден вручную запускать manticore
Блин, даже не знаю, что за логи необходимо смотреть, что за файл, вероятно при загрузке файла какая та ошибка происходит...

Крон предназначен для выполнения задач по расписанию, непонятно при чём тут автозапуск (и ещё непонятно что такое «модуль», но да ладно)

(ну и ещё запускать Manticore через sudo это офигеть как не круто)

Как быть, как добавить приложение в автозапуск, через консоль...

Ну а такую формулировку можно было прямо в поиск на этом сайте вбить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/968702

Дополнил ответ, не вышло у меня...

В описанных шагах не вижу самого главного systemctl enable

/etc/default/grub  необходимо добавить  init=/lib/systemd/systemd в параметр GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="fsck.repair=yes" но данный параметр у меня занят. Как решить это, я  systemctl установил, не понимаю для чего, когда файлы и каталоги уже были  на сервере

Too few arguments. при выполнении команды systemctl enable, я и стал устанавливать. Иначе не включается, хз, что мне делать, сейчас наламаю дров....

Ура все работает, спс
